# How can I retrieve first item from a Collection?

Tags: c#, collections, c#-3.0

I dont know how to retrieve first Item from this collection :

```
IGrouping<string, Plantilla> groupCast = group as System.Linq.IGrouping<string, Plantilla>;
```

I also tryed :

```
IGrouping<string, Plantilla> firstFromGroup = groupCast.FirstOrDefault();
```

but not works cause and explicit conversion already exist

Comment: Could you post the query you're using to get "group" in the first place?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not just use `var`?

```
var firstFromGroup = group.First();
```

As for the reason you're getting an error, I'm guessing either the Key or Element is different than what you think they are. Take a look at the rest of the error message to see what types the compiler is complaining about. Note that if there is an anonymous type involved, the only way to get it is using `var`.

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet <myproject.Models.Image>' does not contain a definition for 'First'

Comment: @alamnaryab You probably forgot to include `System.Linq`. [`First` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_First__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (based on your partial solution):

```
foreach (var group in dlstPlantillas.SelectedItems)
{
    var groupCast = groupCast = group as System.Linq.IGrouping<string, Plantilla>
    if(groupCast == null) return;

    item = groupCast.FirstOrDefault<Plantilla>();  
    if(item == null) return;

    // do stuff with item
}
```

Comment: How much is the memory cost from a var? also anonymous types are more heaviest than a knowed type?

Comment: A var is free. when you do var x = "x"; the compiler can see that "x" is a string, and so it writes String x = "x"; It all happens in the compiler, and the code that comes out in your .EXE file will be identical

Answer (score 0):

This is my partial solution :

```
foreach (var group in dlstPlantillas.SelectedItems)
                {
                    IGrouping<string, Plantilla> groupCast = group as System.Linq.IGrouping<string, Plantilla>;

                    if (null == groupCast) return;
                    foreach (Plantilla item in groupCast.Take<Plantilla>(1)) //works for me
                    {
                        template.codigoestudio = item.codigoestudio;
                        template.codigoequipo = item.codigoequipo;
                        template.codigoplantilla = item.codigoplantilla;
                        template.conclusion = item.conclusion;
                        template.hallazgo = item.hallazgo;
                        template.nombreequipo = item.nombreequipo;
                        template.nombreexamen = item.nombreexamen;
                        template.tecnica = item.tecnica;
                    }
                }
```